# Regex to validate length of alphanumeric string

Tags: c#, .net, regex, validation, alphanumeric

I have the following regular expression:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+( [a-zA-Z0-9]+)*$
```

I'm trying to validate a string between 0-10 characters, the string cannot contain more the two spaces in a row or cannot be empty. The string cannot contain any special characters and can be case insensitive and can include hyphens.

How can I limit input to between 0-10 characters?

I tried

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+( [a-zA-Z0-9]+{0,10})*$
```

but it does not work.

Comment: `if (str.Length > 10)`?

Comment: Do not try to do everything with one regular expression... that will most likely drive you up a wall. For length, you can use the `.length` property provided by the .NET framework. I'd recommend you use multiple regular expressions to perform smaller, much less complex tasks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
^(?!.*  )(?=.*[\w-])[\w -]{1,10}$
```

This uses a negative look-ahead `(?!.*  )` to assert there are not two consecutive spaces, and a positive look-ahead `(?=.*[\w-])` to assert it has at least one non-space character (I assume "empty" means "only spaces").

Note that if it can't be "empty", it can't be zero length, so the length range must be 1-10, not 0-10.

Of tiny note is the fact that you don't need to escape the dash in a character class if it's the first or last character.

Comment: The empty check can probably be removed as we have a required field validator on the control anyway

Comment: OK, but the question did call for regex assertion that there was at least one non-blank. In case someone else comes along later to use this answer, they may not have that extra layer of checking.

Comment: Yep, that's my bad. Would adding `\w` allow for latin\accented characters too?

Comment: `\w` includes all "letters", "digits" and the underscore character. "Letters" means any unicode "letter" (includes accents, greek, arabic, the works). "Digits" includes arabic, chinese "numbers" too.

Comment: Excellent. Ending up using: `^(?i)(?!.*  )(?=.*[a-z0-9-])[\wa-z0-9 -]{1,10}$`

Comment: `\w` includes a-zA-Z0-9. I've updated the answer. It's a lot simpler now. Hopefully it still works for you

Answer (score 2):

```
(?i)([a-z?0-9?\-?]\s?){0,10}
```

Case insensitive, between 0-10 length, matches any combination of letters, numbers, hyphens and single spaces.

Comment: This matches double spaces.

Comment: As mentioned above, this matches double spaces. Almost there though: `(?i)\w([a-z?0-9?\-?]\s?){0,10}` added `\w` to account for accented characters é as i believe these are allowed

Comment: You sure this matches double space i tested in a few testers and it wont match more than one space? Would you like a link to the testers?

Comment: @Srb1313711 Try `test      test`

Comment: By double space do mean two in a row or two in the whole string?

Comment: Two (or more) consecutive spaces

Comment: In which case im still consfused? Try this tester http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ with the regex i supplied, if more than one space it will stop matching is this not what you want?

Answer (score -1):

I think no "+" when using range.

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+( [a-zA-Z0-9]{0,10})*$
```

Also, you say you accept hyphens, but don't see that here?

So

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+( [a-zA-Z0-9\-]{0,10})*$
```

Comment: This matches a string `AAA  AAA`. The input cannot contain more than two spaces in a row